# How to Migrate Infopath XML form library to Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, list-form, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I want to create PowerApps form for one of my InfoPath forms library. How can I do that. How we can convert XML form library to SharePoint list? Right now InfoPath form have a lot of attachment fields where documents can be uploaded and it exceeds limit of 5MB hence we want to move this to PowerApps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to migrate infopath form to power apps or convert XML form library to SharePoint list.

It's necessary to re-create power app forms.

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/transform-infopath

Comment: How can i add multiple attachment controls in a PowerApp form same like infopath form where multiple files can be attached in separate fields using separate controls.

Comment: Currently, within PowerApps, we could only add single one Attachments control within the Edit form.Actually, if you want to upload multiple files to one record of your SP list as attachments, you could add/upload multiple files within the single one Attachments control.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe then my requirement is not possible with PowerApps. I tried using multiple attachment controls in new form by copying attachment data card, but there seems to be no way to display documents in edit form in respective sections as they are getting stored in backend item in one field only. Is there any other alternative you can suggest for achieving this functionality so that we can submit and show files in individual sections of the form?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late on a response here, but wanted to chime in anyway.

As others have noted, the common approach is to more or less convert the form manually. You'll have challenges in recreating repeating sections and tables, translating InfoPath rules (and code behind) to Power FX, and more.

Regarding your specific challenge with attachments, you could do this if your form was backed by Dataverse instead of a SharePoint list...you can have multiple File data type columns in a Dataverse entity and I'm not personally aware of any limit.  We've successfully converted forms that had several separate attachment controls in them.

Another option would be to setup a separate source (say Azure Blob storage) to store your attachments separate from the form data.  You're moving away from the new/edit form paradigm, but that's frankly where a lot of the InfoPath form migrations end up anyway because of the types of challenges you're trying to overcome.

Disclaimer: I'm the CTO at Kudzu Software, so the following is a bit of product pitch.

[Kudzu](https://kudzusoftware.com/solutions/infopath-replacement) has a SaaS platform that among other things can convert InfoPath forms to Power Apps, our own runtime hosted in a SharePoint-native wrapper, or K2 SmartForms.  We can also convert PDFs of all types, imaged forms, and other source form types.